# How can I run Netty on multiple ports in Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

I have a Springboot application using Netty and I want it to run on multiple ports 8080, 8082, 8084.

I tried using NettyServerCustomizer using the code below, but then it only works on the last mentioned port (8084 in this example)

```
@Component
public class NettyWebServerFactoryPortCustomizer 
  implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory serverFactory) {
        //serverFactory.setPort(8088);
        serverFactory.addServerCustomizers(new PortCustomizer(8080));
        serverFactory.addServerCustomizers(new PortCustomizer(8082));
        serverFactory.addServerCustomizers(new PortCustomizer(8084));
    }
    
    private static class PortCustomizer implements NettyServerCustomizer {
        private final int port;

        private PortCustomizer(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }
    
        @Override
        public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
            return httpServer.port(port);
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot only has a single Netty service. All you are doing is changing the port for the single service.

Adding more Netty services is fairly simple, eg [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/11/25/java-netty-webflux)

However, plugging in all the Spring Boot facilities (handlers, controllers) to provide their ease of use is a serious exercise.